# Appium AndroidUIAutomator2 scroll is very slowly

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-java

When I scroll with the code below, it scrolls very slowly, how can I speed it up?

```
public WebElement scrollToElement() {
    return getDriver().findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"tv_today_campaigns\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Kampanyalar ve Duyurular\"))"));
}
```